# Gaining acces to an element using pointers

Tags: c

I'm doing a C quiz on the internet and came across the following question : 
How to write a[i][j][k][l] using only pointers, I know that a[i] can be written as *(a+i), but further than that I don't know.

Comment: Learn to write **readable** and maintainable code. Don't attend those nonsense obfuscating contests. You won't get a job with obfuscation skills, but they might help you getting fired.

Comment: @too honest for Why so harsh? The question is not easy; it involves understanding how multi-dimensional arrays are represented on the machine-level, and it requires understanding of multiple indirection. True, I'd also strongly discourage anyone writing out the pointer notation for the given example (in production code), but as an exercise to understand it? Perfectly fine... BTW, I'd be truly grateful if you could give me a hint why my other question about passing things to functions is "too broad". I'm really at a loss there.

Comment: @GermanNerd: I'm not harsh. And that's not about machine-level representation, it's still C as explained in every good textbook. Finally: this does not help understand arrays/pointers. I'd be the first to support it, if it would. There is no need for a 2D or higher array (if it is any at all), but a simple 1D array is sufficient.

Comment: @too honest for Sure it's C - and can you **truly** understand C without getting at least some conceptual idea of what C translates to on the metal? Some people call it a 'better assembler' (to which I very much disagree, C has quite a lot of higher-level abstractions). So, yes, I perceive your answer as harsh. The OP - most likely- has been given that 'nastiness' as an assignment, to further his/her understanding. I don't consider brushing that off and (almost) redirecting them to 'obfuscated C' as helpful at all.

Comment: @GermanNerd: It's a **quiz**, not an assignment. If not about anything else, the question is clear about this. So, yes he picked it himself. My - and Antti's (which you did not criticise as being harsh, although he says the same) - post are primarily because OP apparently trys to run before he can crouch and then expects others to catch him falling#.

Comment: @too honest for 'Quiz' - 'Assignment' big difference, really? Someone wants to learn and understand. Antti's answer provided a resolution to the OP's question, even if he - in  a closing statement - expresses his view of such quizzes as useless. As to "run before he can crouch" - well, yes, that is the way humans learn. Over-extend yourself, attain the (seemingly) impossible. That's the way **you** learned to walk and run, literally. And you relied on your parents to catch you falling.

Comment: @GermanNerd https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/assignment https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/quiz I leave it here (again) and would appreciate you just stop pinging me further. Danke

Comment: @too honest for And that link shall tell me what? Do you want to instruct me about the German language, or the English one? (Good luck.)

Comment: @too honest for Last 'ping', promise. I perceive a pattern: As if you avoided discourse by withdrawing from a discussion (and also using your elevated privileges due to reputation). I can't do anything about that; but I'd kindly ask you to reconsider this. SO is perceived by many newcomers (myself included) as a pretty rough environment. Is that helpful, in line with SO's mission goal? So much for that - still leaving the (I think friendly) request to clarify what was 'too broad' in my other question. You might have the impression that I'm targeting you - I assure you, that is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

As you stated, `a[i]` can be written as `*(a+i)`, using this principle `a[i][j] == *(*(a+i)+j)
a[i][j][k] == *(*(*(a+i)+j)+k)` and finally `a[i][j][k][l] == *(*(*(*(a+i)+j)+k)+l)`, I know it looks odd but that's how it's done( I think I did the same quiz recently )

Answer (score 0):

You **are** using "only pointers". `a[i]` is defined **only** when either **`a`** or **`i`** is a pointer or is converted to one. `*(a + i)` is **exactly** equivalent to `a[i]` and `*(i + a)` and `i[a]`.

It can be written as `*(*(*(*(a + i)+j)+k)+l)` or for example `*(l + *(k + *(*(a + i) + j)))` for example, but this is not "using pointers" any more than `a[i][j][k][l]`.

---

I'd avoid such a quiz like plague and redirect the entire [host that serves such garbage to localhost](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/block-websites-using-hosts-file/).